# How to enable the C/C++ "Conditional with Omitted Operand" (aka Elvis Operator "?:") in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, conditional-operator, elvis-operator

In the talk [Non-conforming C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAdLwUXRUvg) from CppCon2019 it is introduced the "[Elvis Operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)" in C++, which is a non-standard extension supported by many compilers.

It works by omitting the middle operand of an `?:` expression:

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> read();
std::shared_ptr<foo> default_value();

auto read_or_default()
{
    return read() ?: default_value();
}
```

This is exactly the sample taken from slide 11 of the [presentation](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2019/blob/master/Presentations/nonconforming_cpp/nonconforming_cpp__miro_knejp__cppcon_2019.pdf).

However when I build it on GCC 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, or with GCC 8.2.0 on MinGW, using the `-std=gnu++14` flag, I get this error:

```
error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
     return read() ?: default_value();
                                    ^
```

In the talk it is said that this extension is present in GCC at least since version 4.1.2.

So what's wrong?

Comment: Well, the code you showed [works gobold link](https://godbolt.org/z/4pYCxA).

Comment: Copy and paste from Compiler Explorer to the file dummy.cpp and build with `gcc -std=gnu++17 -o dummy dummy.cpp` it gives that error

Comment: Older versions seems to have a problem with that particular example. If you change your return type to `int` it will work in versions older than 9.1. Upgrade your compiler or try a simpler example.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm using GCC 8.2.0 which is quite recent. I'm not interested in a simpler example, I'm interested in having this one running (it's the example of the talk! and in slide 74 it is reported as working since GCC 4.1.2).

Comment: Indeed it fails on GCC8.2. I don't believe gcc 4.1.2 had shared_ptr. This error looks like a compiler bug related to implementation of `?:` related with `std::shared_ptr`. I could imagine that `read()` returns `std::shared_ptr` that is converted to `bool` on the left side of `?`, so it can't be reused on the right side because types not match, but I know nothing about gcc insides here. `I'm interested in having this one running` - so don't use compiler extensions and non-conforming syntax and just save the `read()` into a temporary variable.

Comment: I also tried with GCC 7.4.0, same error.

Comment: @KamilCuk what kind of answer is "don't use compiler extensions"? The talk is about compiler extensions! I just want to have the sample from the talk working, it's to learn something new.

Comment: @lornova The table on page 74 refers to when the operator came into existence (AFAIK, it's actually older), not when this little example became valid. The use of `shared_ptr` and inferred return type in this example exposes a bug that has been fixed, but not in gcc 7.x and 8.x. (And 8.2 is over a year old.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the basic "conditionals with omitted operand" feature that fails. It's the combination with `std::shared:ptr` that's triggering a bug in GCC fixed in GCC 9.1.

The below code works since GCC 4.1.2:

```
int read();
int default_value();

int read_or_default()
{
    return read() ?: default_value();
}
```